# get profile pictures of all twitter followers

Tags: image, twitter

I want to do a collage with all my twitter followers.
Is there an automated way to get all the profile pictures of my followers (>10 000), without authenticate with twitter. the followers are public anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by writing a script that iterates thru your followers' twitter handle names and use Cloudinary's [twitter profile access](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/twitter_profile_pictures#viewing_profile_pictures) and any of the easy-to-use image transformation features including format conversion, etc.

For example: http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/twitter_name/w_100/billclinton.jpg gives you access to:

[image: Bill Clinton's profile image].